# Getting a 'double free or corruption' error with calls to a function within a recursive function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a recursive function solveCountdownProblem which calls evaluateCountdown which takes an expression in reverse-polish notation format. evaluateCountdown is in a series of nested for loops (in solveCountdownProblem) so is called a lot of times.

```
double evaluateCountdown(string rpnIn) {
    vector<double> stack;
    double a = 0, b = 0;
    string token = "";
    char arithToken;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rpnIn.size(); ++i) {
        if (rpnIn[i] == ' ') {
            if (token != "") {
                stack.push_back(stod(token)); // Push number to stack   
                token = "";
            }
        } else {
            if (find(arithOperators.begin(), arithOperators.end(), rpnIn[i]) != arithOperators.end()) { //if char is arithmetic operator
                // Pop two numbers of stack and perform operation
                // Push result back into stack
                arithToken = rpnIn[i];
                a = stack.back(); stack.pop_back(); // pops and removes elements
                b = stack.back(); stack.pop_back();
                if (arithToken == '+') {
                    stack.push_back(b+a);
                } else if (arithToken == '-'){
                    stack.push_back(b-a);
                } else if (arithToken == '/') {
                    stack.push_back(b/a);
                } else if (arithToken == '*') {
                    stack.push_back(b*a);
                }
            } else {
                token += rpnIn[i]; //add chars to string
            }
        }
    }

    return stack.back();
}
```

It works after some time producing the right calculations but eventually I end up with a memory error 'double free or corruption (out)'. I've used gdb to debug and it produces this backtrace.

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7bee859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7c593ee in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7d83285 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007ffff7c6147c in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff7d85670 "double free or corruption (out)") at malloc.c:5347
#4  0x00007ffff7c63120 in _int_free (av=0x7ffff7db4b80 <main_arena>, p=0x5555555733d0, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4314
#5  0x000055555555a932 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffffd270, __p=0x5555555733e0) at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:128
#6  0x0000555555559dc0 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<double> >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x5555555733e0, __n=4) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:470
#7  0x000055555555932e in std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffd270, __p=0x5555555733e0, __n=4) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:351
#8  0x00005555555588fe in std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffd270, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:332
#9  0x0000555555558953 in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffd270, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:680
#10 0x0000555555556a9a in evaluateCountdown (rpnIn="4 6 5 * + +") at Countdown.h:58
#11 0x0000555555557762 in solveCountdownProblem (operands=std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {...}, targetValue=21) at Countdown.h:172
#12 0x0000555555556d61 in solveCountdownProblem (operands=std::vector of length 4, capacity 5 = {...}, targetValue=21) at Countdown.h:113
#13 0x0000555555556d61 in solveCountdownProblem (operands=std::vector of length 5, capacity 6 = {...}, targetValue=21) at Countdown.h:113
#14 0x0000555555556d61 in solveCountdownProblem (operands=std::vector of length 6, capacity 6 = {...}, targetValue=21) at Countdown.h:113
#15 0x0000555555557e17 in main () at TestCountdown.cpp:19
```

It seems to be pointing to the line 'vector stack;' but I'm not sure why I'm getting a memory error. Doesn't the destructor automatically deallocate 'stack' once it falls out of scope?

Comment: Created that example: https://godbolt.org/z/cPdcYW

Comment: Memory heap (where the memory allocator gets it from) corruption is tricky because it isn't reported at the point the corruption happens. It gets reported during the next allocate or deallocate operation.

It looks like you're on Linux/Unix (using gdb) so learn to use valgrind. It is an excellent tool for discovering memory corruption bugs, thread bugs, all kinds of bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look into evaluated string `"4 6 5 * + +"` you can see that there are not enough operands for the last operation `+` and in your code you do not check if `stack` has enough elements before calling `stack.pop_back()` twice. You need to add that check and act accordingly. Probably cleanest way is to wrap popping in a function:

```
double pop( std::vector<double> &stack )
{
    if( stack.empty() ) { // throw exception, return NaN or whatever logic of your program requires
       ...
    }
    auto r = stack.back();
    stack.pop_back();
    return r;
}
```

then your code is shorter and cleaner:

```
            // Pop two numbers of stack and perform operation
            // Push result back into stack
            arithToken = rpnIn[i];
            double a = pop( stack ); // pops and removes elements
            double b = pop( stack );
```

(and it is better idea to declare and initialize variables when you need them, not in advance)